# Considering the parametric space $\Theta = \mathbb{R}^n$, the set $\{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R^n}: x_1 = x_2 = x_3 \}$ has measure zero?

Tags: lebesgue-measure

My question is very direct: considering the parametric space $\Theta = \mathbb{R}^n$, n>3, I want to know if the set $ \{ (x_1, \ldots, x_n)  \in \mathbb{R^n}: x_1 = x_2 = x_3\} $ has Lebesgue measure zero in $\Theta$?

My intuition say "Yes", for the same reason pointed here: [$\mathbb{R}^n\times\{0\}$ has measure zero in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524151/mathbbrn-times-0-has-measure-zero-in-mathbbrn1)

But, I don't know for sure. If my intuition is correct, I would really like that someone show me the path to rigorously demonstrate it.

Comment: Do you know Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @GEdgar I don't remember this theorem exactly, but if there is a solution using it, I will try to understand it.

Comment: There is a solution using it, so you probably should go try to understand the theorem; then you'll be able to compose the solution yourself.

Comment: @GEdgar A version of this for probability: If $X, Y$ are independent continuous r.v.'s, then $P(X = Y) = 0$. One proof of this uses Fubini's theorem if $X, Y$ have densities, but it can be proven without it using some trickery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Sard's theorem to the linear map $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, x_1, x_1, x_4, \ldots x_n)$, which has rank zero, and the claim follows immediately.

Of course, this is a bit like killing a fly with a sledgehammer --- chances are good that if you're stuck on this particular claim, you've not yet encountered Sard's theorem. But in the rare cases when I want to prove something's neglible, Sard is the go-to tool in my toolbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Indeed, I want to use this result for something bigger, so the mentioned theorem will help a lot.